# Clustering algorithm to group linear equation into groups to achieve certain conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, clustering

Given linear equations of many lines. There exists groups of these lines that intersect near a single point. How do I cluster these groups of lines. See illustration below for better understanding.

[See illustration here for better understanding.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMquV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For an algebraic method you could work out which lines had common intersection points or not. Then group them.

Have you tried researching yet? What have you found?

Start by looking at the capabilities of SAS & SPSS